# Openliberty 23 embedded server does not run servlets after upgrading from openliberty 20

Tags: java, open-liberty

After upgrading from openliberty version 21.0.0.3 to version 22.0.0.1 , my test suites are no longer able to properly load servlets that are placed into the `dropins/` directory. I am receiving the error `Error 404: java.io.FileNotFoundException: SRVE0190E: File not found: /success`. The servlet is defined using the `@WebServlet` annotation and is being loaded properly when used with openliberty 21.0.0.3 .

I have made the conversions from javax to jakarta to resolve any issues with dependency conflicts and have run the server with debug logging to monitor for any error output. The server seems to properly be able to detect my server directory and load it, but fails to load the servlets when making requests: `CWWKZ0135I: The testapp application is using the expanded directory at the *...*/openliberty-jars/wlp/usr/servers/defaultServer/dropins/war/testapp location.`

Although my servlets are properly compiled and stored in the directory that is being used, the servlets continue to fail to be loaded properly.

Answer (score 0):

Moving to a new version of Liberty does not require you to change to use a new version of Java / Jakarta EE.  Since you did though, I assume you updated your server.xml to have Jakarta EE 9 or 10 features.  There is some discrepancy in your question though.  The title says 23 and the question states 22.0.0.1.  I would suggest that you run on a release of Liberty that ends with 3, 6, 9, and 12 since those are the releases that give you the longest support for interim fixes.

In your question you did not give any information about any errors you saw when running your server.  If there are errors in the logs including FFDC logs those should be looked at to see if they provide any insight as to what the problem is.  Adding additional details to the question or in a comment that provides the server.xml content and any errors you see in the logs will help provide additional insight into this problem.  Also please provide some clarification on which version you are actually trying to run on.